# error when importing torchrec module M1 Max

Tags: pytorch, apple-m1

I have a MacBook Pro with M1 Max processor, macOS 12.4. I was following the Pytorch tutorial for their library torchrec (CPU only). When I try to import the library torchrec I am prompt with the following error

```
OSError: dlopen(/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/dlrm_env2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fbgemm_gpu/
fbgemm_gpu_py.so, 0x0006): tried: '/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/
dlrm_env2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fbgemm_gpu/fbgemm_gpu_py.so' (not a mach-o file)
```

Any suggestion in how to solve it? I tried to create a new environment and install again the library but still I am prompt with the same error.